# PhpStorm + GitHub compare files

Tags: github, version-control, phpstorm

I have uploaded a repository. My problem is that I have the same project with some different files on the second machine. How to handle this situation?

Must I clone the project at first in a new folder to the second machine and than merge them on the second machine with the folder before to find different files?

Or is there a easier way to do this? Like connect the second machine to GitHub and check the local with the repository on GitHub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Clone repository on second machine to different folder.
2. On second machine copy files from the folder with changed files to a cloned project and let file manager overwrite existing files. Open cloned repository. Now you can open Version Control and compare changed files.

[image: PHPStorm compare files]

If you are OK with changes, commit them. If you think, the file from repository is correct, pick the file and revert changes for this file.

I recommend to familiarize yourself with Git because you can do it literally without any IDE.

Comment: What exactly means this: "let file manager overwrite existing files" - you mean that i use a merge software or is there any one you mean in phpstorm or vcs?

Comment: It means you copy files using file manager and when it will show you a prompt  "Do you want to overwrite files?" you should answer "Yes". At this moment it will replace existing cloned files from repository with files from your second machine.